# How to find out a particular set of permutations cannot generate the whole symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, algorithms, symmetric-groups

The question is more about the algorithmic side of things. I figure this not-too-inefficient algorithm (if any) in a way is the flip side of the [Schreier–Sims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm) algorithm that checks membership of any permutation $\sigma$ w.r.t the $S_n$-subgroup generated by $\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k\}$. Now the question is, given that set of $\alpha$'s, how to find a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ (if any) that cannot be generated by the set. We can assume $n$ to be sizeable but not too large, while $k$ is small.

Comment: The easiest way would be to choose random elements of $S_n$ and test them for membership in the subgroup $G$. The probability of success with each choice is $1-|G|/|S_n|$, which is typically very close to $1$.

Comment: Actually, if the failure rate each time is $< 1$ (which is then likely to be constant $1 / C$ with sizeable $C$, because $k$ is small), then trying many times seems to be a great algorithm (given that we have a good random process on $S_n$). Otherwise, we could try using the Schreier–Sims on $(12)$ and $(1...n)$. All in all, this is a good enough algorithm.